# How do I prioritize order of posts based on category in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am fetching a list of recent posts using

```
$recent_post = new WP_Query("cat='2,3,4,5,6,8,7,9,10,11,12'&posts_per_page&paged=".get_query_var('paged'));
```

Some of these posts belong to multiple categories and I need to prioritize those posts which belong to category id `8` either on their own or alongside other categories.

I thought of running two separate queries and merge their results, but is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [posts_orderby](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) hook and an SQL [CASE](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-case.html) statement.

Try something like the following.  The case statement for the orderby clause says if it category 8, then assign a value of 1, otherwise assign a value of 2.  then also add any other columns by which you want to sort (in my example, the post_title column).

```
function my_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby_statement = "ORDER BY CASE WHEN $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 8 THEN 1 ASC, ELSE 2 ASC END, $wpdb->posts.post_title ASC";

    return $orderby_statement;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'my_posts_orderby');
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct approach, however when I use this query, none of the posts show up. Any ideas?

Comment: try putting this after your wp_query line: echo $recent_post->request;.  it should print out the sql that was generated.  then we can see where we went wrong.

Comment: you accepted my answer - did you figure out the problem?

Comment: Yes, there was no "term_taxonomy" being used in the generated table so I had to use the taxonomy reference table instead. Your idea and process were perfect, I just had to use a different order query.